# Certificate Type for Document Signer Product

Tags: digital-signature, certificate, digital-certificate, ca

Does anyone know what is certificate type that required to be bought from certificate authority, if I want to develop a product that will signing documents (typically PDF).

So I will keep one certificate and derive another certificates for every product installation, and the product will use the derived certificate to sign documents.

How much it will cost to bought the certificate?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to sign end-user certificates you need to have a CA certificate. Globalsign offers ["root signing" service](http://www.globalsign.com/certificate-authority-root-signing/) . But as I understand it (never used this service myself) the price is quite high and is determined on case by case basis.

For PDF and other document signing CAs offer something like [this](http://www.globalsign.com/document-security-compliance/adobe-cds/). The problem is that CAs charge some enormous money for each PDF signing certificate (I guess it's Adobe's share that is huge).

Comment: Any recommendation beside globalsign? I've send them an email asking similar question, but no respond from them

Comment: @James unfortunately I can't find anything similar to this on other CA's sites. I checked Thawte, Verisign and Comodo, the most popular ones.